# Load PRODUCT_TYPE='cars' and the same time check the last_id bigger the ID

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am doing mutilevel website so I have 2 page; 1st page was choice by type and other page was choice by brand.

**Exp**

**typepage.html**

```
.All
.cars
.bike
.computer
```

I store all my products at 1 table
**database**
**"products"**

```
ID, PRODUCT_NAME, PRODUCT_TYPE, PRODUCT_BRAND
```

And I was using ajax to get into database and check it out, if user in type page and click all it will get all the PRODUCT_TYPE item, but if they click cars, it will look for only PRODUCT_TYPE="cars". But at the same time, I need to use that AJAX to do a infinite load as well, so when user scrolls down, it will load more.

I add to get the last load id so I can track where they stop.

**sql load all**

```
$this->sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE ID > :last_id ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0, :limit";
```

So now I can set the last_id number like 0 it will load 7 item data and when scroll down it will continues from 7.

But what if user click cars and I still want to scroll down? The number will be different because cars item ID maybe [1,5,6,7,8] in database.

**sql load type**

```
$this->sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE ID > :last_id AND WHERE PRODUCT_TYPE='cars' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0, :limit";
```

This is the function _extract

```
# Get an associative array of results for the sql.

public function _extract($sql, $param_1, $param_2) {
    try {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':last_id', $param_1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $param_2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Echo the error or Re-throw it to catch it higher up where you have more
        // information on where it occurred in your program.
        // e.g echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();

        throw new Exception(
            __METHOD__ . 'Exception Raised for sql: ' . var_export($sql, true) .
            ' Params: ' . var_export($params, true) .
            ' Error_Info: ' . var_export($this->errorInfo(), true),
            0,
            $e
        );
    }
}
```

and I have this error **Undefined variable: params**

So my question is how do I load only PRODUCT_ITEM='cars' and at the same time I check the last_id is bigger then ID.

exp
typepage.html, user click car, it loaded data  PRODUCT_TYPE="car", is [1,4,5,9] now when it scroll down, it check again and load ID bigger then 9 at the same time is a PRODUCT_TYPE="card".

How should I write the SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is not generated by the SQL statement. It it is thrown when the system tries to throw your custom Exception. The reason is simple (and stated clearly in the error message). You try to to use the variable $params which is not defined anywhere.

```
      throw new Exception(
  __METHOD__ . 'Exception Raised for sql: ' . var_export($sql, true) .
  ' Params: ' . var_export($param_1, true) . ' ' . var_export($param_2, true) .
  ' Error_Info: ' . var_export($this->errorInfo(), true),
  0,
  $e);
```

Now back to your SQL statement. The syntax is incorrect. The where keywords is only allowed once. Change it to:

```
$this->sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE ID > :last_id AND PRODUCT_TYPE='cars' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 0, :limit";
```